# NDK + Eclipse on Mac OS X: ERROR: Unknown host operating system:

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

Since I updated my NDK version to r10e (and deleted r9b which I've used consistently before), I get the following in Eclipse:

```
/Applications/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build all 
ERROR: Unknown host operating system: 
/Applications/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build: line 40: dirname: command not found
/Applications/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build: line 132: uname: command not found
```

I'm definitely using the correct Mac OS X version of the NDK, and ndk-build works fine from the terminal.
The new NDK path is defined in Eclipse preferences of course.

What's going on here?